# Should I install all released updates before specific update, Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

Let's say I want to install update F and there is also A, B, ..., E updates.

Should I install all of theme one by one and then install F or just F is enough (*in specific version, e.g 1709*)?

**Update** (*adding more info*)

Head to [Windows 10 and Windows Server update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454), in left column, there is **In this release** section, let's say my current build number is `16299.98` and latest released update will bump build number to `16299.847`. between this 2 build number there are lot of released updates, so if I want to update to `16299.847` should I install all released updates one by one, or just latest one (*which makes build number `16299.847`*) is enough?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates are cumulative, and some aren't.

If the update title contains the words "Roll-up" or "Cumulative" they will contain all previous updates to that point.

In general, you will need to look at each update individually to see whether it requires any previous updates prior to installation.

Updates which update the build number will most likely be cumulative and you should only have to install the latest version you're going to.

Answer (score -2):

When we patch systems manually, I always slap in the latest set of updates and reboot.  This usually results in a much smaller subset remaining after the reboot.